# MacOS: USB history (name and timestamp of connected devices)

Tags: filesystems, osx, usb, macintosh, syslog

My external HDD was stolen from me a few weeks ago but I just realised this recently. I really need to know when was the last time I connected this device to my computer. I know it's name, is there any way to get the history of the devices which were connected to the computer?

Comment: don't know much details on MacOS, but if it was linux I would look into the logs which receive a stored copy of the `dmesg` output, which again should tell even't of external HDD being connected

Comment: Should you have no success here then try your luck at [apple.se] because this might be more Apple than UNIX specific but I'm not sure.